# Date formatting in postgresql from existing data

Tags: postgresql

I've date in dd-mm-yyyy format, I need the date in yyyy-mm(month) format. I'm using postgresql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This needs way more information 1) What is the data type of the field that the date value is being stored in? 2) Where do you want the formatted date displayed? 3) In `psql` what does `show datestyle ;` return? 4) Always include software version, so what version of Postgres?  **Add answers as update to question**

Answer (score 3):

`date` values don't have any format. Any formatting you see is applied by your SQL client. To turn a date into a string with a specific format, you can use `to_char()`

```
to_char(the_column, 'yyyy-mm')
```